# Secret chat Telethon doesn’t show the sent message

Tags: telethon

The library `https://github.com/painor/telethon-secret-chat` creates a chat, but when sending a message, it is not displayed in the chat:

```
await client_me.connect()
u_name = "@name"
manager = SecretChatManager(client_me, auto_accept=True)
chat = await manager.start_secret_chat(u_name)
await manager.send_secret_message(chat, message='Here is a secret message')
```

Comment: you should post your code, document the problem.

Comment: What is the "Lonami" reference about?

Comment: May refer to [user Lonami](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4759433/lonami). I think the @ only works in comments, not in posts.